# Is it possible for a Python decorator decorating a instance method/classmethod to know the class the function will be bound to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, descriptor

For a top-level function:

```py
def wrap(f: Callable) -> Callable:
    # Some logic
    return f
```

When such a function is used to decorate another function defined within a `class` body:

```py
class SomeClass:
    @wrap
    # may also be a @classmethod
    def some_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Is it possible within the `wrap` function to somehow inspect the passed-in method (`SomeClass.some_method` in this case) and retrieve the type object of `SomeClass`?

I tried using a debugger to inspect `f` during runtime, but the only relevant info I could find from `f` while it's in the wrapper was the `__qualname__` attribute, which contained the class name.

---

In case you want to know why I am trying to do this: I am trying to create some kind of schema that is based on the method names (the methods are all properties) for a certain class, and store this schema in a `dict` where I would like the keys to be the class objects themselves. Expressed in type signatures:

```py
SchemaSource = TypeVar('SchemaSource', bound=Any)
Method = Callable[..., Any]  # will be bound to SchemaSource
Schema = Dict[Type[SchemaSource], Dict[str, Method]]
```

Of course, I could inspect the class `__dict__` later, or use for example an `__init_subclass__` hook, but because I would like to include some methods in the schema, I figured that decorating the functions would be a good way to provide this information with a single source.

Comment: No, because the class doesn't even exist yet when your decorator is being called.  The name of the class as a string is the best you could hope for at that point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper) mentions, the class doesn't exist yet by the time the decorator is called, and so the function it receives is just a regular function (except that its name mentions the class it will be bound to).

---

For my problem, I ended up doing it `attrs`-style, using an additional decorator to decorate the class as well.

```py
def include(f: Callable) -> Callable:
    """Add function `f` to SchemaBuilder."""
    SchemaBuilder.append(f)
    return f

class SchemaBuilder:
    records: Dict[Type, Dict[Callable, Any]] = {}
    temporary: List[Callable] = []

    @classmethod
    def append(cls, f: Callable):
        """Temporarily store the method in a list."""
        cls.temporary.append(f)

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, target_cls: Type):
        """Associate all methods stored in the list with `target_cls`.

        We rely on the fact that `target_cls` will be instantiated
        (and thus this method called) as soon as all of its (immediate)
        methods have been created.
        """
        cls.records[target_cls] = {k: None for k in cls.temporary}
        cls.temporary = []

# In use:

@SchemaBuilder.register  # called later
class SomeClass:
    @property
    @include  # called first
    def some_property(self):  # will be included
        pass

    @property
    def some_other_property(self):  # will not be included
        pass
```